# Bug in {N} when parsing a css file

Tags: nativescript

I've got the following CSS in my page css file. Crashes in the {N} css parsing code

```css
  @keyframes example
  {
    from { transform: translate(0, 0); }
    to { transform: translate(0, 100); }
  }

  .session-favorite-selected
  {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
```

Comment: What error do you receive? NativeScript supports a subset of CSS, so my assumption is that one line isn't supported in NativeScript even though it is supported on the web.

Comment: I have reproduced and it worked with no problems on my side. Here is the code I've used: https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-issues/tree/master/stack/cssAnimations